# Touch Event In Javascript Seemingly Random?

Tags: javascript, html, touch

I am making a game with the HTML5 canvas, where the player must control a greyhound to catch chicken falling from the sky. The code works with the arrow keys, but I'm trying to add touch events. When the player taps and holds to the left of the greyhound, move left. Right of the greyhound, move right. My current code is as follows:

```
document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
        if (e.changedTouches[0].pageX > greyhound.speedX) {
            greyhound.speedX -= 10;
            greyhound.speedY = innerHeight - 100;
        } else {
            greyhound.speedX += 1;
            greyhound.speedY = innerHeight - 100;
        };
        greyhound.newPos();
    }, false);
}
```

This produces seemingly random results, regardless of where I tap. Also, it doesn't continue moving while I hold my finger on the screen. Any help or critisism is welcome. Thanks!

Note:
I am trying to get this working with only one tap first, then make it work for touch and hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly this is because you're expecting something to keep happening when you hold your finger on the screen, when you're just listening for the initial touch. I'd suggest registering a *touch* and *click* handler to the same function, get it working, then take it from there.

[reference on touch events](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml)

Also, this is somewhat of a side note, but in a fast moving game, calling a method like this on every pixel of change is not going to be hyper performant. You may want to look into something similar to, but maybe not exactly as a [debounce type approach](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)

Comment: I should've been more clear; that's what I'm doing. Making it work on one touch and then making it touch and hold.

Comment: It seems you're comparing the position of the touch, with the speed of the bus. Wouldn't you want to first detect if they clicked to the left or right of the bus?

Comment: my mistake, I should really comment my code! Speed is position, last time I checked... x = speedX is what the newPos() function declares.